# php - Mysql Query working except one filter

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, get

I have below given query which is working except one filter

```
$sql='select * from zonez WHERE zoneprice between :minprice and :maxprice';
    if(!empty($sizes)){
        $sql .='  AND FIND_IN_SET(zonesize,:sizes)';
    }

    if(!empty($categories)){
        $sql .='  AND FIND_IN_SET(webcategory,:categories)';
    }

    if(!empty($minimp)){
        $sql .='  AND websrid IN (SELECT web from stats WHERE time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) GROUP BY srid HAVING  SUM(wh*30) between :minimp and :maximp)';
    }

    if(!empty($search)){
        $sql .='  AND websrid IN (SELECT srid FROM websitez WHERE webtitle LIKE :search)';
    }


    if(!empty($type)){
        $sql .='  AND FIND_IN_SET(zonetype,:type)';
    }           

    $sql .=' group by misc1';
```

Query Binding code

```
$stmt=$this->conn->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindValue(":minprice",$minprice,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(":maxprice",$maxprice,PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if(!empty($sizes)){
            $stmt->bindValue(":sizes",$sizes,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }       
        if(!empty($type)){
            $stmt->bindValue(":type",$type,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        if(!empty($categories)){
            $stmt->bindValue(":categories",$categories,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if(!empty($search)){

            $stmt->bindValue(":search","%$search%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }



        if(!empty($minimp)){

            $stmt->bindValue(":maximp",$maximp,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(":minimp",$minimp,PDO::PARAM_STR);

        }

        $stmt->execute();       
        $resultRow=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            return $resultRow;      
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

I get $minprice and $maxprice from url as &prices=0-10,20-30,5-10

```
$prices=$_GET['prices'];
$gradeprice = str_replace('-', ',', $prices);
$gradepricee=rtrim($gradeprice,',');

$pricenumber = explode(',', $gradepricee);
$maxprice = max($pricenumber) ?: "5000";
$minprice = min($pricenumber) ?: "0";
```

This query get parameters from url 
resutls/?page=1&categories=1,2&sizes=3,4&prices=0-10&imp=2000-1000000&type=1,2&search=blog&sort=1

This query is working except zoneprice filter. This query output results irrespective of **zoneprice between :minprice and :maxprice** Always the zone price between condition is ignored. I tried all possible ways in this filter but this does not effect this query.

Comment: you cant add multiple wherein the same query better to add select * from zonez where 1=1 and in the start of each condition add "and"

Comment: For $imp you have a lot of values unquoted (whereas other strings relate to prepared statement, thus leaving this string to be vulnerable to injection) and also i suppose to replace `$now` with `NOW()`

Comment: This is the updated code. Here only problem. Always zoneprice condition is ignored.

Comment: Show us the generated SQL string

Comment: Since he's using parameterized sql, we can't really see if he's building a query that will return correct data. He needs to re-write the sql to not use parameters until he gets the result he wants, then replace the values with parameters. He also doesn't show how to break out the `minimp/maximp`

Comment: I output comma separated misc values like misc1,misc2,misc3 so on

Comment: Try running it without any of the if statements and see if it returns any values. If it doesn't, then check if your variables :minprice and :maxprice is valid. Also make sure zoneprice is correct.

Comment: Is this the resulting SQL you are looking for? Using the values you posted, this is what is produced: `SELECT * FROM zonez WHERE zoneprice BETWEEN 0 AND 10 AND FIND_IN_SET(zonesize,'3,4') AND FIND_IN_SET(webcategory,'1,2') AND websrid IN (SELECT web FROM stats WHERE time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) GROUP BY srid HAVING SUM(wh*30) BETWEEN 2000 AND 1000000) AND websrid IN (SELECT srid FROM websitez WHERE webtitle LIKE 'blog') AND FIND_IN_SET(zonetype,'1,2') GROUP BY misc1`

Comment: when i replaced :minprice and :maxprice with just values like 0-20 i got correct output.

Comment: Yes MB34 this is resulting query with conditional filters as given my query. Which may or may not exist.

Comment: @Mark can you include the code binding the parameters in your question?

Comment: did you run the query to see if it returned correct values? Note: Without any data, we cannot determine if it does.

Comment: One other comment is that when writing SQL in PHP, it is best to use double quotes because you may need to use single quotes in the SQL itself. i.e. `$sql .="  AND FIND_IN_SET(zonesize,'$sizes')";`

Comment: How do you get $minprice and $maxprice? something like: list($minprice, $maxprice) = explode('-', $_GET['prices']);?
Did you check you get the expected values? If zoneprice is an integer you can also use PDO::PARAM_INT for binding.

Comment: tried PDO::PARAM_INT, but not working

Comment: @MB34  Is my above mentioned query is sql proof?